# String Slicing and Compare in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My target is Slice the string, compare the items and produce the results. Here is my code. But I get the same result for both conditions. The resulting screenshot is attached.

```
string = ["en_english","enc_english"]
for item in string:
    if item[:2] == "en":
        print("selected item : ",item)
    elif item[:3] == "enc":
        print(item, "is selected")
```

**Result**

```
selected item : en_english
selected item : enc_english
```

How to get the correct result ?

Comment: Put specific case before general one

Comment: @azro I think he is trying to print only the 2 first characters but I'm not sure

Comment: What are the first two letters of "enc_english"…?

Comment: BTW,  you're trying to write [`item.startswith('en')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it would be easier to use `item.split('_')`?
like:

```py
string = ["en_english","enc_english"]
for item in string:
    prefix = item.split('_')[0]
    if prefix == "en":
        print("selected item : ",item)
    elif prefix == "enc":
        print(item, "is selected")
```

Only if that is the case you are trying to solve, I just assumed from the question.

Answer (score 4):

Both of the strings trigger on the first condition. Try switching the order to check for the more restrictive case first.

```
string = ["en_english","enc_english"]
for item in string:
    if item[:3] == "enc":
        print(item, "is selected")         
    elif item[:2] == "en":
        print("selected item : ",item)
```